# Another Lost Password

Tags: lateral-thinking, password

I'm on a roll now. I just lost my whole keychain!
Please help me figure out this password ASAP.

Luckily, I saved the process I used to get the password in my email. This is what I wrote:

> Add one to ten and get a pet
>   Switch to the alternative
>   Now make it a candy
>   Put its first year squared between the parts
>   Then flip it with 'S'tandard 'E'ncryption.

On the site I am trying to log-in to, I found my Password Hint.
Password Hint: 2X

Please use the hint to check your answer before posting. If the process was done correctly, then the hint will confirm that the password is correct.

> Don't bother trying to work with the password hint first. It only makes sense once you have the complete password. Follow the process to get the password, then double check it with the hint. I only gave the hint to prevent people from posting many wrong answers.

Alright, I'll add a real hint:

> "Add one to ten" will result in a number. But it's not 11. ;) Think outside the standard mathematical rules.

Comment: I just wasted my lunch hour trying to add ten to 1 to get a pet.

Comment: Considering the hint '2X': Adding $2\times 1$ to the 'n' in 'ten' gives tep (caesar cipher), which is pet in reverse. This could in turn be made into PEZ.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl See my edits. The password hint is only meant and needed to confirm the right answer. It is not any help in discovering it.

Comment: So I've looked at rot10 on each letter of one and can only come up with one animal and followed but got stuck on the last step. Also only one pet that ends with "ten" but following that path I can't find a candy.

Comment: @z.dailey. I changed the tag to lateral thinking. Think outside the box.

Comment: Adding the numbers 10 to 1 gives 55, and I can't think of any pet related to the number 56, so that probably doesn't have anything to do with the solution.

Comment: Adding 1 to 10 makes 101, which could be related to 101 dalmatians? Then hint one will lead to 'Dog' which makes 'God' as the alternative?

Comment: Oh no! Yesterday I spent all that time adding "ten to 1" and now you tell me I should have been adding "one to ten"...

Comment: Hey, you seem to be having a lot of trouble with these lately. Have you considered using a password manager?

Comment: @MichaSprengers, I also thought about 101 Dalmatians yesterday but couldn't think of anywhere to go with it.

Comment: @LN6595: When the password is discovered, will it be a recognizable word, or is it something like "pas1swor44d"?

Comment: I don't know who is vtcing this as "too broad" but: How do you figure it's too broad, when not a single viable answer has even been proffered?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Ha!

Comment: @IanMacDonald The password will be very secure, so no, not a word. Use the password hint to check if your answer is correct. If the password is correct, the hint will make perfect sense.

Comment: @question_asker I can't see how it's too broad. There is but one absolute, reasonable, possible, and correct answer. I assume the vtcer felt it was too hard. But that's not a close reason.

Comment: @MichaSprengers The alternative could be a cat, too, but I can't figure out any kind of cat candy that wouldn't be niche.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha or covered in hair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The password is

> **Xvg3744225Xng**

Explanation:

> **Add one to ten to get a pet.**
>
>    101 : (Dalmatians) - dog
>  **Switch it to the alternative.**
>
>    dog : cat
>  **Now make it a candy.**
>
>    cat : Kit-Kat
>  **Put its first year squared between the parts.**
>
>  Kit-Kat was first produced in 1935, squared is 3744225, so "Kit3744225Kat"
>  **Then flip it with 'S'tandard 'E'ncryption.**
>    "Kit3744225Kat" with rot13 turns into "Xvg3744225Xng"
>  And indeed, "Xvg3744225Xng" contains two letters X and thus agrees with the hint.

Comment: KitKat....sigh..... I should have thought of that =D